# Alternative ways to test / simulate Android Cordova app in browser

Tags: android, cordova, ripple

I have always used [ripple-emulator](https://github.com/ripple-emulator/ripple) to test my Android app in browser.
The project seems to be unmaintened but was still working, until I upgraded to Cordova 7.0.0. Now it does not work anymore: when Ripple starts it just shows:

[image]

So I'm looking for a new way to test my app in browser.

Is there any new way to do it?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 OS.

Thanks

Comment: It might be difficult to do so if your app uses a fair amount of native features. you can always run it on android, with stuff like browsersync

Comment: Well I just need it to just test the front-end part of the app. So don't need to test native features.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908935/how-to-add-live-reload-when-using-the-command-cordova-serve/50786052#50786052

Comment: @rjv, unfortunately it does not work for me!

Answer (score 0):

The Ripple emulator is no longer being updated (as of writing this).
I would recommend that you install the latest version of **Cordova-Simulate** into your application directory. You can read all about it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-simulate

It contains the same features that were available in the ripple emulator.